# DbContext: Lazy Loading with unnecessary database calls?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, dbcontext

I have a very basic example C# program which uses EF6 with DbContext and which contains two classes:

```
MyTable1   1...n   MyTable2
```

I have the following code:

```
// Creation of instances and saving them to the database.
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  var myTable1 = new MyTable1() { ID = 1 };
  var myTable2 = new MyTable2() { ID = 2 };
  myTable1.MyTable2.Add(myTable2);
  context.MyTable1.Add(myTable1);
  context.SaveChanges();
}

// Getting the above objects in another context.
// This part here is what my question is about.
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  var myTable1 = context.MyTable1.Where(e => e.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
  var myTable2 = context.MyTable2.Where(e => e.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
  var myTable2AssignedToMyTable1 = myTable1.MyTable2.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My question is about the second part of the code above.

When lazy loading is enabled, I get three database calls. One for each line. The variable `myTable2AssignedToMyTable1` contains then `myTable2` - which is correct.

When lazy loading is disabled, I get two database calls. One for the first and one for the second line. The variable `myTable2AssignedToMyTable1` contains as well `myTable2` - without a third database call. This makes sense to me because `myTable2` was loaded in line 2.

But: If that third database call is not needed, why is it made when lazy loading is enabled?

When I check the database calls in SQL Server Profiler with and without lazy loading I realize that they are exactly the same (apart from the third call). The data from the third call is the same as in the first or second call. So when the third call is happening, the desired data are already in the context. When lazy loading is disabled, EF realizes it and uses the already loaded data. When lazy loading is enabled it does not realize it and fetches the same data from the database again. Why?

Is it faster than finding the correct instance of `MyTable2` in the context?

Or is it faster than always searching for the correct instance in the context first and then make the database call? One can assume that in most cases the desired data are not already in the context. So I guess the EF designers decided to not check the context first. In most cases it will be a miss any way.

But these are only my assumptions. Knowing the real reason would be interesting.

Comment: i hope my explanation will suffice

Comment: Thanks again for your quick responses. But I think we are not exactly talking about the same thing. My question is: Why does lazy loading load data from the database if it has them already loaded. When lazy loading is disabled EF realizes that the data are loaded already and shows them. When lazy loading is enabled EF does not realize that the data are loaded already and fetches them again.

Comment: ahh, i see, guess my answer was wrong in terms of my understanding :D